# How to assign teacher role to new user in moodle?

Tags: moodle

I created a **new user** in a **moodle** site and I want to assign **teacher role** to this user.

I tried to achieve this using the below steps:

1. Site administration.
2. User.
3. Define role.

These steps couldn't help me to solve this problem, and I see this page: [Assign roles – MoodleDocs](http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Assign_roles).

Can anyone help me to do that...

Comment: i solve the above problem by using the below steps:

Comment: i solve the above problem by using the below steps:
1. front page setting
2. users
3. assign role
now this new user have teacher role. but when i try to add this user as teacher to existing course can't do that....

Answer (score 7):

To assign the teacher role to a user in a course, you should do that [in the course context](http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Assign_roles#Course_context).

1. Go to the course page;
2. Click settings → Course administration → Users → Enrolled Users;
3. In the role column of the user, click on the plus sign;
4. Click on the teacher role, and then remove the student one (x sign).

Comment: What if the user is not enrolled yet? Do you have to wait until he is enrolled in the course?